# Overtaking particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

A particle A. starts from rest and accelerates uniformly by $2ms^{-2}$. Three seconds later another particle B starts from same point and accelerates by $4ms^{-2}$ along the same direction. what is the time taken for particle B to overtake A?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Physics SE! Please note that homework-like questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. See [our meta site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) for more guidance on how to edit your question to make it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the available information:

The accelerations are:

$$a_A = 2$$
$$a_B = 4$$

The time to the overtaking point is:

$$t_A = T + 3$$
$$t_B = T$$

Similarly, both particles have the same starting velocity and travel the same distance to the overtaking point:

$$u_A = u_B = 0$$
$$s_A = s_B = S$$

Hopefully you know that:

$$s = ut + \frac{1}{2}at^2$$

So now we can form two equations:

$$S = \frac{1}{2}a_A(t_A)^2 = (T + 3)^2$$

and:

$$S = \frac{1}{2}a_B(t_B)^2 = 2T^2$$

Therefore:

$$2T^2 = (T + 3)^2$$
$$\Rightarrow 0 = T^2 - 6T - 9$$

Comment: hello beta decay. thanks so much for your help.. i was thinking the same way but instead of taking time for A as T+3, i was using time for B as T-3.

Comment: @rowine Both methods should work